# Parse text and special characters from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I have an issue with parsing text with special characters from XML in SQL Server.

Let's say I have a XML file `Sample.xml` which has the following data:

```
<People>
    <Person FirstName="Adam"
            LastName="Smith"
            Age="44"
            Weight="178">
        <Texts>
            <Text Country="US"
                  Language="EN"
                  TextType="1">&lt;div&gt;First sentence to retrieve.&lt;/div&gt;</Text>
            <Text Country="GB"
                  Language="EN"
                  TextType="2">&lt;div&gt;Second sentence to retrieve.&lt;/div&gt;</Text>
        </Texts>
    </Person>
</People>
```

I prepared the following SQL script which can parse everything except two sentences in the `<TextType>` attribute:

- First sentence to retrieve
- Second sentence to retrieve

```
DECLARE @x XML
SELECT @x = f FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Sample.xml', single_blob) AS C(f)
DECLARE @hdoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x
SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/People/Person/Texts/Text')
WITH (
        FirstName varchar(max) '../../@FirstName'
        , LastName varchar(max) '../../@LastName'
        , Age varchar(max) '../../@Age'
        , [Weight] varchar(max) '../../@Weight'
        , Country varchar(max) '@Country'
        , [Language] varchar(max) '@Language'
        , TextType varchar(max) '@TextType'
        )
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

Could you please help me to add the column with the sentences mentioned above?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OPENXML` is old and basically deprecated, it has numerous issues.

You should use the newer XQuery functions `.nodes` and `.value` to retrieve your data.

Your primary issue is that you have XML stored as string inside another XML. You need to retrieve it as `nvarchar(max)`, then cast it using `TRY_CONVERT`.

```sql
SELECT 
    FirstName  = x1.Person.value('@FirstName', 'varchar(100)'),
    LastName   = x1.Person.value('@LastName' , 'varchar(100)'),
    Age        = x1.Person.value('@Age'      , 'int'),
    Weight     = x1.Person.value('@Weight'   , 'decimal(9,5)'),
    Country    = x2.Text.value('@Country' , 'char(2)'),
    [Language] = x2.Text.value('@Language', 'char(2)'),
    TextType   = x2.Text.value('@TextType', 'int'),
    value      = v.InnerXml.value('(div/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @x.nodes('People/Person') x1(Person)
CROSS APPLY x1.Person.nodes('Texts/Text') x2(Text)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( TRY_CONVERT(xml, x2.Text.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')) )) v(InnerXml);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0d637aac70da6ce1800bc0c55491269)

Note the way there are two calls to `.nodes`, and one feeds into the next.

You can even feed this in straight from `OPENROWSET`

```sql
SELECT 
    FirstName  = x1.Person.value('@FirstName', 'varchar(100)'),
    LastName   = x1.Person.value('@LastName' , 'varchar(100)'),
    Age        = x1.Person.value('@Age'      , 'int'),
    Weight     = x1.Person.value('@Weight'   , 'decimal(9,5)'),
    Country    = x2.Text.value('@Country' , 'char(2)'),
    [Language] = x2.Text.value('@Language', 'char(2)'),
    TextType   = x2.Text.value('@TextType', 'int'),
    value      = v.InnerXml.value('(div/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Sample.xml', single_blob) AS C(f)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( TRY_CONVERT(xml, C.f) )) C2(AsXml)
CROSS APPLY C2.AsXml.nodes('People/Person') x1(Person)
CROSS APPLY x1.Person.nodes('Texts/Text') x2(Text)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( TRY_CONVERT(xml, x2.Text.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')) )) v(InnerXml);
```

I recommend you fix whatever is generating this XML, ideally you would pass through the inner XML without stringifying it.